# Merging Multiple Vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I am wondering if there is any tool or way to kind of Weld (merge) multiple vertices at once,

[image: two loops to merge]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge at Center* doesn't do the job.

[image: Merge at Center result]

Doing by one takes a lot of time so it's inefficient way of going about it.

Comment: In this specific example you can achieve this easily by:
1. select both loops
2. scale to 0 on the Y axis ( keyboard: S --> Y --> 0 )
3. remove doubles ( keyboard: W --> remove doubles )

Comment: That actually did help, but by removing double, does it somehow can affect textures or mesh in any bad way?

Comment: Removing doubles merges vertices that are closer to each other than a threshold value (which you can control on the last action panel - F6).
As long as the threshold value is small, this usually fixed problems rather than causing any (when the value is too high, it might merge verts that aren't really double). Regarding textures, I guess it depends how you map them to your model. In some cases you might need to redo or adjust your UV mapping.

Comment: CTRL + E --> bridge edge loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Bridge tool from the Loop Tools addon to connect the loops, then slide them into each other and remove doubles. You can also cut a new loop between them to get the exact midpoint.

Comment: You can use blender's built in bridge tool.